# I used PBEKeySpec class to hash password and It works, but sometimes not

Tags: java, hash

I tried to make hash of my password. The problem is that the hash works well but sometimes it is not. I'm not sure if this API is reliable. In the terminal jihoon.kim was failed to log in although it has same salts and hashes between creation and log in(upper one is from creation and lower is from log in). jihoon.lee has different hash from same salts. jihoon.park succeeded on the log in. It was from one time running without close and rerunning of the code. I searched Internet but I couldn't find same case or any help. Is there any other way to solve or resource that I can refer? Thank!
[hash creation and log in result of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKPKO.png)

```
public class HashPassword {
private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
private String userName;

public HashPassword(String userName){
    this.userName=userName;
}
/* Set password to new value, zeroing out password */
/**
 * creating random salt and save the salt and password to database
 * @param pass
 * @throws IOException
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 */
public void setPassword(char[] pass) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException  {
    byte[] salt = new byte[12];
    random.nextBytes(salt);
    saveBytesSalt(userName, salt);
    saveBytesPassword(userName, hashPassword(pass, salt));
}

/* Encrypts password & salt and zeroes both */
/**
 * creating hash with the salt
 * @param pass
 * @param salt
 * @return hash
 * @throws GeneralSecurityException
 * @throws IOException
 */
public byte[] hashPassword(char[] pass, byte[] salt) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    KeySpec spec = new PBEKeySpec(pass, salt, 100000, 128);
    SecretKeyFactory f = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA256");
    byte[] hash = f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded();
    Base64.Encoder enc = Base64.getEncoder();
    System.out.printf("salt: %s%n", enc.encodeToString(salt));
    System.out.printf("hash: %s%n", enc.encodeToString(hash));
    return hash;
}

/**
 * Saving the password value created from this class to database via the username
 * @param userName
 * @param password
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void saveBytesPassword(String userName, byte[] password) throws IOException {
    AddUserData.addPassword(userName, password);
}

/**
 * Saving the salt value created from this class to database via the username
 * @param userName
 * @param salt
 * @throws IOException
 */
private void saveBytesSalt(String userName,byte[] salt) throws IOException {
    AddUserData.addSalt(userName, salt);
}
```

Comment: What you describe would be a pretty serious bug when used for the main purpose of that function. I'd guess that the number of iterations is so large that some limit is reached sometimes. Check the web server/runtime for CPU, RAM behavior and request timeouts.